# How to determine length of buffer at client side

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a server sending a multi-dimensional character array

```
char buff1[][3] = { {0xff,0xfd,0x18} , {0xff,0xfd,0x1e} , {0xff,0xfd,21} }
```

In this case the buff1 carries 3 messages (each having 3 characters). There could be multiple instances of buffers on server side with messages of variable length (Note : each message will always have 3 characters). viz

```
char buff2[][3] = { {0xff,0xfd,0x20},{0xff,0xfd,0x27}}
```

How should I store the size of these buffers on client side while compiling the code.

Comment: You cannot (you could change your protocol to decide to send the sizes before the content). Did you consider using a textual protocol like [JSON](http://json.org/) ?

Comment: You will have to send the size over network before the array. Or you could add a terminating sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The server should send information about the length (and any other structure) of the message with the message as part of the message.

An easy way to do that is to send the number of bytes in the message first, then the bytes in the message.  Often you also want to send the version of the protocol (so you can detect mismatches) and maybe even a message id header (so you can send more than one kind of message).

If blazing fast performance isn't the goal (and you are talking over a network interface, which tends to be slower than computers: parsing may be cheap enough that you don't care), using a higher level protocol or format is sometimes a good idea (json, xml, whatever).  This also helps with debugging problems, because instead of debugging your custom protocol, you get to debug the higher level format.

Alternatively, you can send some sign that the sequence has terminated.  If there is a value that is never a valid sequence element (such as `0,0,0`), you could send that to say "no more data".  Or you could send each element with a header saying if it is the last element, or the header could say that this element doesn't exist and the last element was the previous one.

Comment: how should I approach this problem using c++

Comment: As Galik mentioned in another comment, adding a terminating sequence or a 'special message' to the data you send is another viable solution, depending on your requirements. On the client side, you would read messages until you read the 'special message' { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }. Then you know there is no more data expected. Of course this only works if you are 100% certain { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } isn't going to be a valid message. To add, the way you approach this problem does not depend on your choice of programming language.

Comment: @Jonsnow29 That would depend on how you are sending the data in the first place?

Comment: @AtlasC1 I think the extra paragraph covers the terminating sequence option, what do you think?